# Copy text file from a isolated server

Tags: linux, networking, scp, gateway

I have a linux remote machine which is isolated from the rest of the world. To access to it I have first to connect via ssh to a gateway. When connecting to the gateway I have no prompt, but I must input the name of the final machine. If everything is correct I have access to a console (bash) to the final remote machine.

Now I want to transfer a text file from the final machine to my laptop. I cannot access to Internet (no mail, no ftp, ...). I cannot scp to the gateway. Presently I copy and paste the text from an editor on the remote machine to my laptop, but I am wondering if there is a better method.

Comment: Yeah. Pasting screenshots into MS Word. Otherwise: Sorry, this remote machine of yours really seems to be closed down.